# very basic java method

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and am writing a stack class using array.

So I have a method in this class called pop

```
 public int Pop(){
   if (current_size >0)
    { // do something 
      return ele;
     }
     // return nothing  <-- ths is where error is
     }
```

Since i have the return type int.. the class is always expecting to return something.
How should I tackle such cases where the method wil return something if the condition is true else it wont shouldnt return anything?
Thanks

Comment: There's....a *lot* wrong here.  First, *where* is your array?  You're not using it in this method.  Second, it's difficult to decide what to return when the stack is empty, since any primitive int may be a valid entry in the stack.  Third, I don't see anything that reduces the size of the stack or adjusts where the end of the stack is pointing to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must always return something (unless your method is `void`) or throw an exception. You could try this:

```
public int pop() {
    if (current_size > 0) 
        return ele;
    throw new EmptyStackException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what your desired behavior is, it is hard to tell you, but I can provide a couple suggestions.

1. If you want to truly return nothing, you should change the return type to be the `Integer` wrapper class rather than the `int` primitive.  This way you can return `null` which would be nothing.
2. If this is an exceptional case, perhaps you want to `throw` an `Exception`.

   ```
   if (evaluateSomething()) {
       // do something in response...
   } else {
       throw new RuntimeException("You can't do that!");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You could raise an exception when the stack is empty, or you could return a special int like -1 if your stack never has negative numbers.

```
throw new StackIsEmptyException();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a return statement or throw an exception for all possible exit point.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your method is `void`, you must either return a variable or throw/catch an exception. Something like this should do;

```
    public int pop() 
{
    if (current_size > 0) 
        return ele;                  //return variable
    throw new EmptyStackException(); //throw new exception
}
```